# How shall we reply to an editor after a minor revision of a paper?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, editors

I received the editor's comments as follows:

> The revised version of your manuscript xxx has been reviewed by our referees. Referee A is now satisfied with your paper, while Referee B is more or less satisfied but supplies a long list of remarks that need to be taken into account. While we cannot make a definite commitment, we will probably accept your paper for publication, provided you make changes that we judge to be in accordance with the appended comments (or other satisfactory responses are given).

I have revised my manuscript and prepared a detailed explanation of how I have dealt with all of the comments of reviewer B. Actually, there are just 7 comments on the manuscript.

Now, I am going to reply to the editor. Could you suggest me how to write a reply to the editor like this, such as ''While we cannot make a definite commitment, we will probably accept your paper for publication, provided you make changes that we judge to be in accordance with the appended comments''? And What should I need to notice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: “Dear editor, here is the revised manuscript. We corrected it according to the recommendations of the reviewers, as is specified in the attached document. We hope that the manuscript is now satisfactory and suitable for publication.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s nothing going on behind the scenes here. Just send it back and say “I’ve made the requested edits, I hope the manuscript is now satisfactory,” or whatever you would normally say to an editor when sending back a paper.

You seem to think that there’s some kind of implicit social dynamic going on with the editors comments. There isn’t.